# Crash with Glide on android app

Tags: android, listview, android-glide

My application closes every time I try to see the images. Can you explain why?

I think maybe the problem is the string `Glide.with(getApplicationContext())`, maybe it isn't correct. But for Android Studio I don't have errors:

All other elements are ok, the problem is only glide.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String url= "MY ARRAY";
    ...

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
        new gson().execute(url);
    }

    public class gson extends AsyncTask<String,String, List<MovieModel> >{

    ....
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    private List<MovieModel> movieModelList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public Adapter(Context context, int resource, List<MovieModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        movieModelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            holder.fruitsfoto = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.fruits);
            holder.fruitsname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pics);
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
try {
Glide.with(MainActivity.this)//getApplicationContext()
        .load(ModelList.get(position).getImage())
        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return false;
    }
})
        .into(imageView);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
holder.fruitsname.setText(ModelList.get(position).getName());
return convertView;
            }
        }
    }
```

Update: The show images don't follow the list of array. Need a solution.

```
    public Adapter(Context context, int resource, List<MovieModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        ModelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
.....
    try {
    Glide.with(MainActivity.this)//getApplicationContext()
            .load(ModelList.get(position).getFruits())
            .into(imageView);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Edit:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(convertView == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
        holder.fruitsfoto = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.fruits);
        holder.fruitsname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
1)holder.image = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pics);
2)ImageView imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pics);            
convertView.setTag(holder);
//the first cause a crash
//the second return "Variable 'imageView is never used'"
```

This is the console error:

```
09-28 17:19:42.079 30111-30111/app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                            Process: app, PID: 30111
                                            java.lang.NullPointerException
                                            at app$1.onResourceReady(MainActivity.java:309)
                                            at app$1.onResourceReady(MainActivity.java:301)
                                            at com.bumptech.glide.request.GenericRequest.onResourceReady(GenericRequest.java:522)
                                            at com.bumptech.glide.request.GenericRequest.onResourceReady(GenericRequest.java:507)
                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob.handleResultOnMainThread(EngineJob.java:158)
                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob.access$100(EngineJob.java:22)
                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob$MainThreadCallback.handleMessage(EngineJob.java:202)
                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post logcat error

Comment: Glide.with(getApplicationContext()) replace with Glide.with(MainActivity.this)

Comment: If you're facing problem regarding images are wrongly placed, please feel free to share the code of your Adapter here.

Comment: Your adapter code is not sufficient. Where's the bindView method. Hope the Glide loads the images inside bindView method. Please remove the ... and paste the full code of your adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if you have added the `INTERNET` permission in your application manifest?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="viewpager.nested.example.com.testapplicationforso">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And yes, it always good to have your glide image loading code segment inside a `try/catch` statement.

```
try {
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(yourUrl).into(img);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Update:

About the images wrongly placed - I could see that in your `getView` function, you did not find the `ImageView` properly. You need to find the `ImageView` inside `convertView` like the other items in the list like this.

```
holder.image = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pics);

// Then load the image in holder.image
Glide.with(MainActivity.this)//getApplicationContext()
    .load(ModelList.get(position).getFruits())
    .into(holder.image);
```

Comment: I change the code for try your solution:
try {        Glide.with(MainActivity.this)//getApplicationContext()
                .load(movieModelList.get(position).getImage())
                .into(imageView);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

It works, i see the images, but i have different problems:

The show images don't follow the list of array: for example the photo of apple appears into banana list, and if swipe down it gone from banana list and appears instead a photo of a banana.
Why do not I see them in the correct order?

Comment: I've added a comment too under your question. Please share your adapter code in the question. Try editing your question with the adapter code.

Comment: i modified my post.

Comment: Check my comment in your question and please leave a comment there after modifying it again so that I can get notified.

Comment: Try to see now.

Comment: Can you please check the updated answer. You need to load the image in your `holder.image`.

Comment: Glad to know that helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was using Glide in a static method, thus causing memory leaks. Try using it directly in activity or fragment, not in static method.

Hope this helps someone.